# Android app crash when switched in tab layout/fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Android Development and I am experiencing a problem. My app is like crashing i have 2 Activities which is Home and Main, the Main activity has a 4 fragments and when i switched from first to 2nd it is working but when i switched to the 3rd and/or 4th the app is returning to my Home Activity and yet the app doesn't throwing an error so basically i am clueless about what is happening.

I am populating a RecyclerView in my 4th Tab/Fragment and this is what i don't understand, if the table from database is null or nothing to throw in RecyclerView the tabs are working and i can switch any of the 4 fragments but if the database has a value to throw that populating the RecyclerView that's when the problem occurs it is returning back to Home Activity, it is like crashing but it doesn't close the Application

Main Activity

```
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    }


    //TABS
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabPager);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter= new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainTabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser == null)
    {
        sendToStart();
    }
    else
    {
        mUserRef.child("online").setValue(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser != null) {

        mUserRef.child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    }
}


private void sendToStart()
{
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

4th Fragment

```
public FriendsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

    mFriendsList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
    mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    //mFriendsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return mMainView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(

            Friends.class,
            R.layout.users_single_layout,
            FriendsViewHolder.class,
            mFriendsDatabase


    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder friendsViewHolder, Friends friends, int i) {

            friendsViewHolder.setDate(friends.getDate());

            final String list_user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

            mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {

                        String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                        friendsViewHolder.setUserOnline(userOnline);

                    }

                    friendsViewHolder.setName(userName);
                    friendsViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());

                    friendsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Open Profile", "Send message"};

                            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                            builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                    //Click Event for each item.
                                    if(i == 0){

                                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                        profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                        startActivity(profileIntent);

                                    }

                                    if(i == 1){

                                        Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), Home.class);
                                        chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                        chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                        startActivity(chatIntent);

                                    }

                                }
                            });

                            builder.show();

                        }
                    });


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    };

    mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

Edited.. I look up on logcat and i found this on my "Package Name (DEAD)" and after clicking this is the error and I removed the SectionsAdapter since the errors are coming from the Fragment.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object 
reference
    at 
 com.example.gab.quadrantms.FriendsFragment$FriendsViewHolder
.setDate(FriendsFragment.java:177)
    at 
 com.example.gab.quadrantms.FriendsFragment$1.populateViewHolder
(FriendsFragment.java:89)
    at com.example.gab.quadrantms.FriendsFragment$1.populateViewHolder
(FriendsFragment.java:85)
```

and also is this kind of error?

```
11-03 02:27:09.593 27447-27447/com.example.gab.quadrantms 
E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
```

Comment: There must be an error happened,if you can't see any error in your logcat then chanage a new device or emulator and try again.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @.

Comment: Yes sir I found the error in the logcat and I already added it to my question. @AlexMamo

Comment: The stack trace provides your best guidance, FriendsFragment.java, line #177, you have a null object reference

Comment: @CSmith I already solved it, as I read the lines 1 by 1 and I saw where is the object and why is it null. Thank you for the help :)